# Change class of label element in nput box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new in AngularJS. I'm trying to change the class of a label element while I'm doing something on an input text.

What I have is the following:

```
<form>
  <input id="first_name" type="text" ng- blur="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName" ng- focus="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName" />
  <label for="first_name" ng-class="{'active':moveLabelFirstName}">MyName</label>
</form>
```

This adds/remove the class active whenever focus/blur is activated on the input box. What I would like in addition is to add one more class, e.g. onchange, whenever the input is empty or non empty.

I have seen in angular that ng-empty and ng-non-empty are added, but it's on the input and not on the label.

How could I make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use check the `model` property assigned to input element

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```css
.ng-empty{color:red;}
.ng-not-empty{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-blur="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName" ng-focus="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName" />
    <label ng-class="{'active':moveLabelFirstName, 'ng-empty' : !firstName, 'ng-not-empty' : firstName}">MyName</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <input id="first_name" type="text" ng-model="name" ng-blur="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName" 
   ng-focus="moveLabelFirstName=!moveLabelFirstName"/>
<label for="first_name">
  <span ng-class="{'active': !moveLabelFirstName}">  MyName </span>
  <span ng-class="{'active': moveLabelFirstName && !name}"> Editing</span>
  <span ng-class="{'active' : moveLabelFirstName && name.length > 0 && name.length < 3 }">Name should be minimum 3 letters</span>
  <span ng-class="{'active' : moveLabelFirstName && name.length >= 3 }">Perfect</span>
</label>

</form>
```

This will work 
Live example : https://jsbin.com/yihugu/edit?html,output

Hope this helps. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this example...

```
<style>
input.ng-invalid {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>

<body>
<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
 Enter your name:
  <input name="myName" ng-model="myText" required>
</form>
</body>
```